# Codeigniter to Send form data to api url

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I have form (5 fields which includes 1 file attachment field), whose field's data I need to submit on db as well as send on api url.

If I put api url in `action` of form tag then form data being send successfully. BUT I can't add api url in action coz like this form will redirect to that api url by leaving the site.

So to avoid putting api url in `action` I used following code to send form data to api url.

```
 /* Endpoint */
    $url = 'http://url_here';

   $tmpfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    
    $data = array(
        'to' => $to,
        'cc' => '',
        'message' => $subject,
        'attachment' => '@'.$tmpfile.';filename='.$filename,
        'message' => $message
    );
    
    $ch = curl_init($url);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

     /* Define content type */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
        
    /* Return json */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
    /* make request */
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    /* close curl */
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

This code giving this error.

```
{"timestamp":"2022-03-09T07:23:54.873+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"","path":"/QRCodeGenerator/sendmail"}
```

While searching for solution, I also tried adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept:application/json'));
```

For `Accept:application/json` to work I did convert array into json using `jason_encode()`. But it was still giving same error.

Where I am getting wrong?

> UPDATE

I tried this code also which I got from postman where api working fine.

```
$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'http://url_here/QRCodeGenerator/sendmail',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('to' => 'example@gmail.com','cc' => '','message' => 'This is test subject','body' => 'this is body msg','attachment'=> new CURLFILE('/path/to/file')),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

But this is giving blank page. `$response` printing nothing.

Comment: I told you in comments here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71391900/1427878 yesterday, that we can hardly answer this, without knowing what exactly this API _expects_ to receive. And yet here you have still not given any such information.

Comment: @CBroe I told that in my post what api axpect. He expect 4 text data and 1 file attachment. That's all. I wrote this code, And I am not getting why it is not working. That's why I was hoping if any expert can find out whats missing or wrong in code. I am not asking to give me code. I am asking to tell my mistake in my code.

Comment: _" told that in my post what api axpect"_ - but that doesn't tell us _how_ exactly it wants this data to be send. _"If I put api url in action of form tag then form data being send successfully."_ - well then that surely will not have been a JSON request, because HTML forms do not send those (not unless any additional JavaScript was involved to intercept the submission, and make the request itself) - so all we can tell by now, is that sending JSON is probably not the correct way here. You likely want to make a `multipart/form-data` request then.

Comment: @CBroe `You likely want to make a multipart/form-data request` Yes, that probably will work. But I am not sending data in json. Because I am not using `json_encode()` function. For testing I used it but later I removed it.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated my post to show what code I used to send data as multipart/form-data.